# Apache running in infinite loop, request URI too long

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I want to read a value from cookie and pass that value as a query string, for that i have used the following rules

```
**1 : "RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^preferenceLocale=([^;]+) [NC] 

RewriteRule ^/*(.*) http://192.168.132.148/cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=%{HTTP_HOST}&ybpage=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]"**

if cookie value is available then i need to execute fallowing set of condition and rule,  

**2 :"RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} preferenceLocale=([^;]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^/*(.*) http://192.168.132.148/cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=%{HTTP_HOST}&ybpage=$1&preferred_locale=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]"**
```

These rules works fine individually but if both the rules are placed its failing with the error Request UIR is too long,

if we see the logs the HTTP_HOST is replaced by some junk values

```
192.168.132.148 - - [11/Sep/2012:11:23:15 +0530] "GET /cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=192.168.132.148&ybpage=cs/Satellite&preferred_locale=1302157366636&pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=test100.fwqae148.yelladworks.in&ybpage= HTTP/1.1" 414 345 "http://test100.fwqae148.yelladworks.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
```

Comment: Are these rules on the same host as what you are proxying to (192.168.132.148)?

Comment: Yes these are on the same host

Answer (score 0):

U need to give only One condition , and follow it with the required rewrite for Cookie.

Remove the condition for "without-cookie" Rewrite.PUT the Redirect with condition first, than the Redirect without Condition.

```
 if cookie value is available then i need to execute fallowing set of condition and rule,  

**2 :"RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} preferenceLocale=([^;]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^/*(.*) http://192.168.132.148/cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=%{HTTP_HOST}&ybpage=$1&preferred_locale=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]"**\


 RewriteRule ^/*(.*) http://192.168.132.148/cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=%       {HTTP_HOST}&ybpage=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]"**
```

Comment: If I remove without-cookie rewrite condition for the request which don't have a cookie value is not redirected to any page. It shows the Apache home page.

Comment: If you remove the condition(not the redirect) , so it will  direct all requests to Rewrite address. If its not a cookie request.

Comment: I edited my answer. remove misplaced comments if any , and u can use the code as such.

Answer (score 0):

If the rules and the proxied destination are on the same host, the rules are going to be applied each time. For example:

1. Incoming request, rules are applied
2. No `preferenceLocale` cookie, query string is appended
3. URL is sent to mod_proxy to be proxied
4. mod_proxy makes the request
5. repeat from step 1.

That's why the query string keeps repeating itself, and notice how after the 2nd to last instance, the `ybdomain=` parameter turns from `test100.fwqae148.yelladworks.in` to `192.168.132.148` (the IP you are proxying to). This continues to happen because the cookie `preferenceLocale`, or the lack thereof, gets passed along to each proxied request, so the check against the cookie will always be true.

You need to add a few conditions to check the query string, so that it doesn't proxy the request again:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !preferenceLocale=([^;]+) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pagename=YBWrapper
RewriteRule ^/*(.*) http://192.168.132.148/cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=%{HTTP_HOST}&ybpage=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} preferenceLocale=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pagename=YBWrapper
RewriteRule ^/*(.*) http://192.168.132.148/cs/Satellite?pagename=YBWrapper&ybdomain=%{HTTP_HOST}&ybpage=$1&preferred_locale=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]
```

Comment: Now after placing the above rules the request is always handled by the first set of rules. Even the preferenceLocale cookie exists, its executing the first one only. For correctness of the 2nd rule i commented the first one and checked, its working fine. But the same Apache home page if no cookie value exists.

Comment: @user1659994 try removing the `^` in front of the `preferenceLocale` in the first condition.

Comment: I removed ^ in front of the "preferenceLocale", it doesn't make any difference. Can you please give me some suggestions.

Comment: @user1659994 no clue why it doesn't work for you. I copied and pasted the above rules (just now), replaced `192.168.132.148` with `localhost`, and placed it in a blank htaccess file in a new instalation of apache and I'm getting the correct proxied requests with and without the `preferenceLocale` cookie.

Comment: Could you please send me a sample file which is working for you.

Comment: @user1659994 [As you can see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kH8Ar.png), the left is the request, the middle is the proxied server handling the proxied request, and the right is the entirety of my htaccess file, which is what I posted in my answer

Comment: Is there any tools that can test the execution flow of Rules, and where we can see the values set to that ?

Comment: @user1659994 Yes, but you need to have access to server/vhost config. You can turn on rewrite logging via: `RewriteLog /path/to/rewrite.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 5`